# Nested Stack View won't respond to changing axis based on size class

Tags: ios, objective-c, size-classes

I have 4 simple views that I want to lay out either vertically 4x1 (if horizontally compact) or horizontally 2x2 (if in any other combination) on iPhones. I also added wC+vC as horizontal 2x2 because iPhone landscape is wC+vC.

My interface builder layout looks like this:

[image]

When display a preview of an iPhone 4s in landscape and portrait in Assistant, I get what I expect:

[image]

However! When I use the simulator for any iPhone and put it into landscape, I get this:

[image]

No matter what I try, I can never make both TopStack and BottomStack display as horizontal. IF I delete the bottom stack, the top becomes horizontal. But as soon as the bottom stack comes into play, the top stack doesn't respond.

I have even tried this in code for just wC+vC:

```
-(void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
if( self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact && self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact ) {
    [self.TopStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    [self.BottomStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
} else {
    [self.TopStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [self.BottomStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
}
```

}

When I debug, I can verify that the top stack is in fact in `UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal` but does not correctly display.

Does anyone have an idea on what is wrong??

Comment: Does it function correctly on device?

Comment: It functions on the device the same as the simulator. Tested on an up to date iphone 6

Comment: And just to confirm this is a Universal app and not iPhone only?

Comment: Correct i tried both universal and iphone and it didnt matter

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing some weird behavior in a test project. These Stack Views aren't behaving as expected, but what I'm getting is dramatically different from what you're seeing. (Edit: I had the wrong fill property)

Comment: Yeah i am wondering whether this is a bug in IB. I tried hardcoding it and i confirmed the state change in the stack view and it didnt update the display.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. This looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an ongoing bug with `UIStackView`. It appears there were similar issues in beta versions of iOS 9.0 and there may still be some lingering issues with regards to embedded `UIStackViews`:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/adapting-stack-views-with-size-classes/

Adding the following code as indicated in the above article does resolve this issue, but at the cost of being screen size agnostic and losing some of what makes Size Classes useful:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    if (size.width > size.height)
    {
        [self.topStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [self.bottomStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.topStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [self.bottomStack setAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    }
}
```

**Demonstration Xcode Project can be downloaded [from here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2LipNeZs2EYc3U1bS1rSmg2S1k).**

Comment: This does work as expected! Is there any constant that Apple gives as the width or height of a size class rather than using magic numbers for device width or width>height?

Comment: Honestly I doubt it given the purpose of Size Classes to prevent this exact sort of code. If it were me, I would probably implement the meat of this method on a `UIViewController+StackViewHack` category or similar to make it easier to revert/update once Apple fixes nested `UIStackView` layouts. It might also be a good idea to file a radar for this bug and link to this SO question.

Comment: Good idea. It sounds like this is the only solution until Apple fixes things. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: You might be able to perform a check on the value of `self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass` from within this method instead instead of using the height/width check. It's not something I've tried, but I can give a shot the next time I'm near my laptop and report back my findings/update the answer.

Comment: Right I tried doing that and because this is a ````viewWill...```` it appears to be called before the ````traitCollection```` updates the size classes. So the view controller still retains the old size classes before the switch. Originally I had hoped to use ````traitCollectionDidChange:```` to get a hook after the traitCollection updates (which works successfully), but then ````setAxis:```` does not seem to visually take affect - even though programmatically I can verify it has the new axis.

Comment: Wondering if this has been fixed in Xcode 8 and iOS 10. Will test with the above demo project on simulator once I get it all downloaded and installed.

Comment: As of the date of this comment, this appears to be fixed in Xcode 8 iOS 10.